# twig template suggestion for comment reply form

Tags: theming, comments

there is no template suggestion for a comment reply form in Drupal 8, how can i create one?
i am not talking about the reply form displayed in the node for which Drupal suggest a template :

```
field--node--comment--article.html.twig
```

I'am talking about the form in the redirection page after we click "reply" in a comment. there is no  template suggestion, only this template is suggested

```
form.html.twig
```

Can you please tell me how can i create a specific template in my .theme file of my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you want to achieve. But you can easily add another template suggestion based on the form ID by implementing [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter) for forms. The form ID can be found in the `$variables` then. But no matter if you are on the node route or the reply route this will simply give you `comment_comment_form`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $form_id = $variables['element']['#form_id'];
  // Add template suggestion based on form ID.
  $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $form_id;
}
```

If you want to do something different on the reply route you could check the current path for the `/reply` and `/comment` arguments OR check if the route parameters contain a PID, which would be the parent comment ID.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add template suggestion based on form ID.
  $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $variables['element']['#form_id'];
  // Add template suggestion based on form ID and parent comment ID.
  if ($pid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('pid')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $variables['element']['#form_id'] . '__reply';
    $suggestions[] = 'form__' . $variables['element']['#form_id'] . '__reply__' . $pid;
  }
}
```

Which will give you the following theme suggestions.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * form--comment-comment-form--reply--1.html.twig
   * form--comment-comment-form--reply.html.twig
   * form--comment-comment-form.html.twig
   x form.html.twig
-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. It works, but why you've put **rebuild_cache_access** at the beginning of the function? The proper function name for a theme is `THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_form_alter()`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just forgot to anonymize the module/theme name.